# Every isomorphism of subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$ is of the form $\varphi(x)=qx$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $A$ and $B$ be subgroups of the additive group $\mathbb{Q}$. If $A$ is isomorphic to $B$ and $\varphi : A \rightarrow B$ an isomorphism, then show there is $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\varphi(x)=qx$ for all $x \in A$.

Okay so this is what I did:

If $A=\{0\}$ then this is vacuously true so assume $A \neq \{0\}$. If $\frac{a}{b} \in A$ then $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{a}{b}+...+\frac{a}{b}=a$ where there were $b$ summands in the previous sum. Therefore $A$ contains all integers which appear as numerators of fractions in $A$. Let $d$ be the GCD of all such integers. Note that $d$ is defined since $A \neq \{0\}$. Since $d$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of these integers we have $d \in A$. Therefore every $\frac{a}{b} \in A$ can be written as $\frac{nd}{b}$ for some some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and in fact $\frac{nd}{b} \in A$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore the mapping $\frac{nd}{b} \mapsto \frac{n}{b}$ is surjective and is easily shown to be a well defined isomorphism of $A$ with some subgroup $A'$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing $\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore we may assume WLOG that $1 \in A$ or, equivalently $d = 1$. Then for any $a \in A$ we have $\varphi(a)=\varphi(a\cdot 1)=a\varphi(1)$.

We now claim that $q=\varphi(1)$ is the desired $q$. Indeed if $\frac{a}{b}$ is any element of $A$ then $\varphi\big(\frac{a}{b}\big)=a\varphi \big(\frac{1}{b}\big) \implies \varphi \big(\frac{a}{b}\big)=1\cdot\varphi \big(\frac{a}{b}\big)=\frac{b}{b}\varphi \big(\frac{a}{b}\big)=\frac{ab}{b}\varphi \big(\frac{1}{b}\big)=\frac{a}{b}\varphi \big(\frac{b}{b}\big)=\frac{a}{b}\varphi(1)$.

> I am fairly certain that my proof is correct, but I am curious if there is a better way of doing this without the part about the isomorphic copy of $A$ containing $1$. I was playing around with it for awhile and it seems that the $\varphi(1)$ should be replaced with some fraction involving $\varphi(d)$ in such a proof. Also if someone has another shorter or cleaner proof I am very interested to see it.

Comment: If $\phi$ is your isomorphism, define $q = \phi (1)$.  Then for integers n we instantly get $\phi(n) = nq$.  Similarly $q = \phi(1) = \phi(\frac nn) = n\phi(\frac1n)$ implies that $\phi(\frac 1n) = \frac qn$  Not hard to finish from here.

Comment: @lulu but $A$ may not contain 1

Comment: You can simplify your proof by noting that $A \cap \mathbb Z$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ and so of the form $d\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @coldnumber Ah, true.  Read too quickly!

Comment: @lulu I did too. Wrote a whole answer based on that :S. I'm fixing it.

Comment: @ lhf I basically used that when I said you can write every element as $\frac{nd}{d}$.

Comment: @lulu and coldnumber  I did this as well at first, it's very inconvenient that they didn't give us that $1$ was in the subgroup..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure of how much this helps, but I'll just show why you can take $q=\varphi(d)$ without needing to use the isomorphism with a subgroup of $\Bbb Q$ containing $1$.

Suppose $A\neq \{0\}$ and let $d$ be as in your proof, or, as lhf commented, the integer such that $A \cap \Bbb Z = d\Bbb Z$.

Then for an arbitrary element $\frac {nd} b \in A$, we have

$$
\varphi\left(nd\right)=\varphi\left(\frac {nd}b+\cdots +\frac {nd}b\right)=\varphi\left(\frac {nd}b\right)+\cdots+\varphi\left(\frac {nd}b\right)= b\varphi\left(\frac {nd}b\right) \\\implies \varphi\left(\frac {nd}b\right)=\frac 1b \varphi({nd}).
$$

Also,
$$
\varphi(nd)=\varphi(d+\cdots+d)=\varphi(d)+\cdots+\varphi(d)=n\varphi(d)
$$

Putting these together, we get that for an arbitrary element $\frac {nd}b \in A$

$$ 
\varphi\left(\frac {nd}b\right)=\frac nb\varphi(d) = \frac {nd}{b}\left(\frac{\varphi(d)}{d}\right).
$$

This means that we can take $q=\frac {\varphi(d)}{d}$.

Comment: I am uncomfortable with the statement $\varphi \bigg(\frac{nd}{b}\bigg)=\frac{1}{b}\varphi(nd)$. Why can you move $\frac{1}{b}$ out of the $\varphi$? Obviously you can do it for integers  since it's an isomorphism and multiplying by integers is just repeated addition. But I'm not sure that you can extend this to rationals as well ?

Comment: I got there by dividing the equation above it by $b$

Comment: ah I see now. I think there is still a problem. Since we wanted to show that for any $x \in A$ that there is $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\varphi(x)=xq$. Which would mean that we would want $\varphi\bigg(\frac{nd}{b}\bigg)=\frac{nd}{b}\varphi(d)$.
I was also having this issue  when I was trying to do it without translating it to an isomorphic copy with 1.

Comment: Whoa I agree. Let me think of how to fix that.

Comment: Well, can't we take $q = \frac {\varphi(d)}{d}$? It may not be in $B$, but it is definitely a rational number because the gcd is positive.

Comment: I was trying to work with $q=\frac{\varphi(d)}{d}$. I might have over looked that it didn't actually need to be in $A$ when I was doing that. I can't remember atm, I'm pretty tired now. I think I was only able to get it to work out for the integers in $A$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26143/discussion-between-coldnumber-and-andrew).

Comment: Okay I think all of the kinks are out of it now. I'll look at it more in the morning and decide if it's "smoother" and decide which proof I like better.

Answer (score 2):

Having blundered at first, I fear another error, but here goes...

pick any $x \in A$ (other than x = $0$) and define $q \in \mathbb Q$ by $q = \frac{\phi(x)}{x}$ Then at least we have $$\phi(nx) = n\phi(x)=nqx\;\;\;n\in \mathbb Z$$.

Now take any $y \in A$.  Certainly $y = \frac mn x$ for some integers m and n.  But then $ny = mx$ so we have $$n\phi(y)=\phi(ny) = \phi(mx) = m\phi(x)\;\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;\;\phi(y)=\frac mn\phi(x)= \frac mnqx=qy$$